# Cakephp DISTINCT

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I use `DISTINCT` to get unique user id with highest value for `total_time_driven_at_this_trip` and also pull `user_name` from another table which has belongsto relations based on `user_id`?

I tried this...

```
$this->set('tripNsws', $this->TripNsw->find('all',array('limit' => 20,'fields' => array('DISTINCT(TripNsw.user_id)','TripNsw.total_time_driven_at_this_trip'),'group' => array('TripNsw.user_id') ,'order' => array('TripNsw.total_time_driven_at_this_trip desc'))));
```

but it's not working.

I suppose you need to get below....

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id),`total_time_driven_at_this_trip` FROM `trip_nsws` order by `total_time_driven_at_this_trip` desc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// see below url

    http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1018/find


 array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'), //array of field names
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'), //string or array defining order
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset'=>n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)



// or try this



function some_function() {

    $total = $this->Article->find('count');

    $pending = $this->Article->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending')));

    $authors = $this->Article->User->find('count');

    $publishedAuthors = $this->Article->find('count', array(
    'fields' => 'DISTINCT Article.user_id',
    'conditions' => array('Article.status !=' => 'pending')
    ));

}
```

Comment: i dont think your answer is related to the question - at all

Answer (score 7):

**Correct Syntax for DISTINCT keywork in cakephp**

```
$this->set('banners', $this->Banner->find('all',array('fields'=>'DISTINCT Banner.id')));
```

Make sure DISTINCT uses in fields array.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntaxis is

```
$this->set('tripNsws', $this->TripNsw->find('all',array('fields'=>'DISTINCT TripNsw.user_id')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider setting it as a Virtual Field ( http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1608/Virtual-fields )

```
$this->Model->virtualFields['distinct_user'] = 'DISTINCT Model.user_id';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a GROUP BY in the query to get the same result as DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

```
'fields' => array('DISTINCT Model.Modelfield')
```

or

```
'fields' => array('Model.id','DISTINCT Model.Modelfield')
```